# Create and invoke generic async method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a situation where I need to determine the type of an object dynamically (compile time is fine) within a declaration for a generic.

I have a method like this:

```
private async Task<T> Post<T>(string path, Request data)
{
    var authPath = GetAuthenticatedPath(path);
    var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync<Request>(authPath, data);
    return response;
}
```

The problem is that I really need it to operate more like this:

```
private async Task<T> Post<T>(string path, Request data)
{
    var authPath = GetAuthenticatedPath(path);
    var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync<data.GetType()>(authPath, data);
    return response;
}
```

Because I need it to format the data variable as it's ActualRequestType rather than the Request type when it does the conversion to JSON.  The problem is you can't do data.GetType() within the type declaration.

Comment: Reflection is probably the only way. However, writing reflection to work properly with `await` might very well be impossible. Ouch. So you might have to actually write a switch to handle all possible types...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that's fine.  I just really need to know about making the type work within the angle brackets.  I'm going to try a few of the answers below and see if the help.

Comment: Removed my edit... and inlined "Compile-time works fine for me." comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify your signature to this:

```
private async Task<T> Post<T, TRequest>(string path, TRequest data)
    where TRequest : Request
{
    var authPath = GetAuthenticatedPath(path);
    var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync<TRequest>(authPath, data);
    return response;
}
```

The condition will make sure you are still receiving valid `Request` objects and the actual type will carry on to the `PostAsJsonAsync` call.

Comment: This is not quite what was asked for. This will use the compile-time type of the data parameter, not the run-time type.

Comment: @mikez Actually, this seems to work pretty well. An edit was made to my question indicating 'run-time'.  My needs are either.  Compile-time works fine for me.  I'll edit the question back to remove the run-time restriction.

Comment: +1. @claydiffrient - sorry about misunderstanding your problem - this indeed is standard way to specify type at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

method [PostAsJsonAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh944521%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) return `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` so possibly you don't need return generic, only get like this

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post<T>(string path, T data)
{
    var authPath = GetAuthenticatedPath(path);
    var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync<T>(authPath, data);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Probably will need to constrain `T` to a `Request` too.

Comment: But `T` is the response type and maybe is different than the request type